# Sequelize 4.0: Custom instanceMethods for all sequelize models

Tags: sequelize.js

how do we create custom instance methods to be applied/inherited by all models with sequelize 4.2? In sequelize 3 we used to have an "instanceMethods: {custom1: function (){} }" in the "define" section of a main model which was extended to all other models. How do we achieve the same behaviour with sequelize 4.0?

Comment: Can you point towards how the main model thing worked with sequelize < 4.
Couldn't find anything myself and it would be really helpful

Comment: Hi @Shivam, we used to have a main "define" object like below (example taken from "Application wide model options" section of V3 documentation [ https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/getting-started/ ] -> "The Sequelize constructor takes a define option which will be used as the default options for all defined models."


`{
 // don't add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
 timestamps: false,
 
 // instance methods - inherited by all models
 instanceMethods: {
  _myCustomMethod: function () {
   // some process here ...
  }
 }
}`

Comment: And all our models extended this "base" model with define options. And now in sequelize 4.0 the instanceMethods are declared directly on the model's prototype... How to we achieve same behavior as with sequelize 3.0 when we want to have custom instanceMethods applied to (inherited by) all our models ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Instance methods get called independently of the "define" section now. I just got mine to work on V4 by doing something like this:

```
const User = sequelize.define('users', {
 name: {type: Sequelize.TEXT}
});
User.prototype.custom1 = function() {
  //function
};
```

I can still call the instance method in any file in which the User model is imported. I hope this helps! This is the doc I used for reference: